# If $f(g(x)) = 4x^2-8x$ and $f(x)=x^2-4$, then what's the value of $g(x)$?

Tags: functions

I'm a little stuck with this simple function:

If ${f(g(x)) = 4x^2-8x}$ and ${f(x)=x^2-4}$, then what's the value of ${g(x)?}$

Any tips?

Comment: Thank you for all your responses!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By setting $y:=g(x)$ we see that:
$$
4x^2-8x\,=\,f(g(x))\,=\,f(y)\,=\,y^2-4\,=\,g(x)^2-4
$$

Thus:
$$
g(x)^2 = 4(x^2-2x+1)=4(x-1)^2
$$

which implies that $g(x)=\pm2(x-1)$.

Comment: Thank you. It seems like I'm a little confused about the definition of function. Can you explain in detail why ${f(g(x))}$ is equal to ${g(x)^2−4}$?

Comment: I've edited my answer. Is it clearer now?

Comment: Now it's very clear. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Hint: complete the square in $4 x^2 - 8 x$, to express it as $(\ldots)^2 - 4$.

Answer (score 0):

If $g$ is a polynomial, then note that the degree can't be higher than $1$. Suppose $g(x)=ax+b$. Then

$$f(g(x))=f(ax+b)=a^2x^2+2abx+b^2-4$$

Now we want $a^2=4$, $2ab=-8$, and $b^2-4=0$. Two such solutions are $a=2,b=-2$, or $a=-2,b=2$.

Pluggin those back in, we have

$$f(2x-2)=4x^2-8x+4-4=4x^2-8x$$

and

$$f(-2x+2)=4x^2-8x+4-4=4x^2-8x.$$

Answer (score 0):

Since $4x^2-8x=g^2-4$, $g^2=\left( 2x-2\right)^2$ so $g$ may be chosen as either $2x-2$ or $2-2x$, or even a function that can be either depending on the value of $x$, e.g. $\left| 2x-2\right|$ or $-\left| 2x-2\right|$.

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align}
f(g(x))&=4x^2-8x\\
g(x)^2-4&=4x^2-8x\\
g(x)^2&=4x^2-8x+4\\
&=4(x^2-2x+1)\\
&=4(x-1)^2\\
&=[\ \!2(x-1)\ \!]^2\\
\implies g(x)&=\pm2(x-1)
\end{align}

Comment: Thank you. The only thing that isn't clear is why ${f(g(x))}$ is equal to ${g(x)^2−4}$?

Comment: @stevekai2 That's the definition of $f(x)$